# Is it possible to define a administrator to a specific group in linux?

Tags: users, groups

I was given the following task

- Designate John Doe as the group administrator;

I am very confused with the meaning of "the group administrator".

Is it possible to give privileges to a user (johndoe) to make changes to only a designated group? Or, does it mean something more broad and allow that user (johndoe) to make changes to any group?

Comment: The concept of a "group administrator" does not exist  so the question is unanswerable.

Comment: @Rinzwind, thank you for pointing it out that such concept does not exist. I suspected but given I don't have tons of experience, I was not fully sure.

Comment: From `man gshadow`: *administrators: It must be a comma-separated list of user names.
Administrators can change the password or the members of the group.*

Comment: @steeldriver that is a bit of hmm. So can they change users passwords and anything else so the mention of "as the group administrator" is to me the same as "as the  administrator"

Comment: It's possible you're supposed to add the user to the "adm" group, using something like "gpasswd -a user adm", or you might be supposed to add the user to the administrators list for a group with "gpasswd -A user group". Which one is unclear, but now you have what you need to do either. (Note that the "gpasswd -A" command may remove all other administrators from the group you use it on, so you might want to resort to editing /etc/gshadow manually if there's other users already set as administrators of the group in question.)